# The clean up command in TortoiseSVN is not working. Why?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

While trying to update svn **"403 forbidden error"** is showing.I am not able to update the project.*While entering into each folder i can update*.
But in one folder again same error occurs.

**When a new file added in svn and when i try to update it is not updating in my local copy**..

Svn sometimes prompt to execute clean up command.But when clean up is given. It shows:

> TortoiseSVN has stopped working

I have seen in many cases that locking may be the problem. I tried releasing the lock, but noting is locked.

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.6.0 and i am using windows7

When clean up is given, it ends up due to below mentioned problem details

```
*Problem signature:*      Problem Event Name:   BEX   Application 
Name:   TortoiseProc.exe      Application Version:  1.6.0.15855   
Application Timestamp:  49c4da8e      Fault Module Name:    MSVCR90.dll   
Fault Module Version:   9.0.30729.4926   Fault Module 
Timestamp:  4a1743c1    Exception    Offset:    0006c955   Exception 
Code:   c0000417    Exception   Data:   00000000   OS 
Version:    6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.4      Locale ID:    1033   Additional 
Information 1:  3721     Additional
Information2:   3721b00010d0d8c722df055a03e879e0   Additional
Information 3:  0b39    Additional Information
4:  0b391ced731efbba00379ff9de0b1dcd
```

By deleting the particular folder and adding again solved update issue.But still **Clean Up is not working**

Comment: Does it actually show **Clean up NOT WOrking**?

Comment: @oliver TortoiseSVn client has stop working.. This message is showing